# Retornar algumas colunas da consulta usando LINQ

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-core

Tenho uma consulta que me retorna todas as colunas e estou usando apenas duas colunas (`id` e `nome`) no meu `select2`, pensei em trazer apenas estas colunas, gostaria de saber se e possível trazer na consulta apenas duas colunas `Fornecedor`.

Tenho o seguinte:

**IFornecedorRepository**

```
Task<IEnumerable<Fornecedor>> ObterParaAutocomplete(string text);
```

**FornecedorRepository**

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Fornecedor>> ObterParaAutocomplete(string text)
{
    return await Db.Fornecedores.AsNoTracking()
        .Where(x => x.Nome.Contains(text))
        .OrderBy(p => p.Nome)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

**FornecedoresController**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> ObterFornecedor(string text)
{

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            result = ""
        });
    }
    else
    {
        var dados = _mapper
            .Map<IEnumerable<FornecedorViewModel>>(
                await _fornecedorRepository.ObterParaAutocomplete(text)
            );
        return Json(new
        {
            result = dados
        });
    }

}
```

**Resultado Json**

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não deu certo alguma solução?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic tudo certo! grato!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se pode criar uma `ViewModel` com dois campos (no seu campo `id` e `nome`) e no momento de utilizar `ORM` `Entity` `Framework` faça o seguinte:

```
public class ViewModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

e depois no sua `Interface` `IFornecedorRepository` crie um método:

```
Task<IEnumerable<ViewModel>> ObterParaAutocomplete(string text);
```

e o implemente na classe `FornecedorRepository`:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ViewModel>> ObterParaAutocomplete(string text)
{
    return await Db.Fornecedores
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Where(x => x.Nome.Contains(text))
        .OrderBy(p => p.Nome)
        .Select(c => new ViewModel { Id = c.Id, Nome = c.Nome })
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

e isso é muito bom para o desempenho pela quantidade de informações que realmente são necessárias.